# Stieffel manifolds of Hilbert spaces

Tags: geometry, manifolds, hilbert-spaces

This question [Contractibility of the sphere and Stiefel manifolds of a separable Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199133/contractibility-of-the-sphere-and-stiefel-manifolds-of-a-separable-hilbert-space)
mentions
the Stieffel manifolds of orthonormal $n$-frames $$V_n=\lbrace x_1,\dots,x_n\in \mathscr{H} \mid  i\neq j\Rightarrow\langle x_i|x_j\rangle=0\text{ and }\|x_j\|=1,\forall j\rbrace$$ of a infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$.

How is $V_n$ a manifold? Is it some sort of a submersion level set theorem?

There are some books in the question
[Reference on Infinite Dimensional Manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705175/reference-on-infinite-dimensional-manifold?rq=1),
but I haven't been able to find an explanation of specific examples (and if I find a suitable reference I expect there'd be also Grassmannian)...